# Making a cat less scared

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology, fear

My cat is a very sweet guy, and around a year old. He's very cuddly, but still gets scared by my wife and me around the house. There is no shortage of love that he receives, and we thought he would possibly grow out of the skittishness, but is still afraid of us from time to time.

For instance, if we move around the house too quickly, he will take off running. He likes to follow myself around and meows to get my attention,  but if I get too close he will be out of reach. If I grab him after a mini chase, he will purr and cuddle, but this happens all the time. He does the same to my FIL, who will be able to pet him, and follows them around the house, but is just out of reach. Like I said above he is super cuddly and loves pets but still has a tiny skittish nature.

Are there any techniques or strategies used by all you cat owners proven to help a naturally skittish cat to become less scared around people?

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please take the [tour], it only takes a minute. And could you elaborate how he expresses his fear in actions? Does he hide? Puff up his tail? Attack you? Please [edit] your question and add more details about the behaviors that make you conclude he's afraid of you.

Comment: It would also be interesting if there are certain things you and your wife do that make him scared. Maybe like moving quickly? Bending down to pet him?

Comment: How long have you had him? What have you tried?